# CMake project that consumes dependencies built from a Bazel project

Tags: c++, cmake, bazel

I've a simple Bazel project that uses glog (which depends on gflags).

```
# WORKSPACE

load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "com_github_gflags_gflags",
    sha256 = "34af2f15cf7367513b352bdcd2493ab14ce43692d2dcd9dfc499492966c64dcf",
    strip_prefix = "gflags-2.2.2",
    urls = ["https://github.com/gflags/gflags/archive/v2.2.2.tar.gz"],
)

http_archive(
    name = "com_github_google_glog",
    sha256 = "122fb6b712808ef43fbf80f75c52a21c9760683dae470154f02bddfc61135022",
    strip_prefix = "glog-0.6.0",
    urls = ["https://github.com/google/glog/archive/v0.6.0.zip"],
)

# BUILD

cc_binary(
    name = "main",
    srcs = ["main.cpp"],
    deps = [
        "@com_github_google_glog//:glog",
    ]
)

# main.cpp

#include <glog/logging.h>

int main() {
    LOG(INFO) << "Hello, World!";
    return 0;
}
```

When I run `bazel build main` this builds the binary successfully. I want to use the glog + gflags dependency include directory and library files built by this Bazel project in a CMake project (for several reasons that I will not elaborate here).

Is there a way to do this? I started with this partial attempt of including the directory from the Bazel build output, but running into a compile error.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(btest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

include_directories(/path/to/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/external/com_github_google_glog/_virtual_includes/glog)
include_directories(/path/to/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/external/com_github_gflags_gflags/_virtual_includes/gflags)

add_executable(main main.cpp)
```

However this produces an error like this:

```
In file included from ../main.cpp:1:
/path/to/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/external/com_github_google_glog/_virtual_includes/glog/glog/logging.h:122:17: error: incomplete type in call to object of type 'struct GLOG_EXPORT'
  LogMessageTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

Above error seems the compiler could not able to use class/obj defined from [glog](https://github.com/google/glog/blob/master/src/glog/logging.h.in) framework. Have you tried initializing as [this](https://github.com/google/glog#getting-started) and check.